# Playframework - How to create subpackages under app/views?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2.4 (Java version) but I'm also interested in solutions for >2.4. This is my problem. I want to structure the content of my template folder under app/views. So I'd like to create some sub packages under app/views but get compilation errors. Here is, what I've tried so far:

1. Create new subpackage via eclipse

   `app/views/mediaViewers`
2. Put a template `standardViewer.scala.html` in it

   `app/views/mediaViewers/standardViewer.scala.html`
3. Try to access the template from controller class via

   `views.mediaViewers.html.standardViewer.render()`
4. Rebuild play project

   `activator clean; activator clean-files; activator run`

When calling the appropriate route I get:

```
[error] .../Viewers.java:18: package views.mediaViewers.html does not exist
[error] views.mediaViewers.html.standardViewer
[error] ..../Viewers.java:21: package views.mediaViewers.html does not exist
[error] views.mediaViewers.html.standardViewer
[error] .../app/controllers/Viewers.java:24: package views.mediaViewers.html does not exist
...

[error] (compile:compileIncremental) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application - 

! @765kicfe1 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[package views.mediaViewers.html does not exist]
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call a view template from the controller you should alwayes prefix the name of the view with "views.html", so the call to standardViewer.scala.html would be :

```
views.html.mediaViewers.standardViewer
```

you can verify this if you took a look at the generated files under target/scala-/twirl as indicated in this picture : 
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS5Yg.png)

Answer (score 1):

The package path in the controller is wrong! Use this pattern:

```
`views.html.your-package-goes-here.your-template-goes-here.render()`
```

Or more concrete:

> 3. Try to access the template from controller class via
>
> views.mediaViewers.html.standardViewer.render()

Has to be:

`views.html.mediaViewers.standardViewer.render()`